# Apache HBase start error

Tags: java, database, windows, apache, hbase

I configured Apache HBase, but when I run start-hbase.sh this error shows:

> Error: Could not find or load main class Files.Java.jre7.bin:.cygdrive.c.WINDOWS.Sun.Java.bin:.cygdrive.c.WINDOWS.system32:.cygdrive.c.WINDOWS:.usr.local.bin:.usr.bin:.cygdrive.d.OracleDB.product.12.1.0.dbhome_1.bin:.cygdrive.c.ProgramData.Oracle.Java.javapath:.cygdrive.c.WINDOWS.system32:.cygdrive.c.WINDOWS:.cygdrive.c.WINDOWS.System32.Wbem:.cygdrive.c.WINDOWS.System32.WindowsPowerShell.v1.0:.cygdrive.c.Program

I use Windows 10.

Comment: Might want to edit your question and add more details like which tutorial/link have you referred and what steps have you followed?

Comment: https://hbase.apache.org/cygwin.html